# Would gcc -O take effect for linked static library?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation

such as:

```
gcc test.c mystaticlib.a -o test -O2
```

would `-O2` take effect for `mystaticlib.a`, or just `test.c`?

Comment: Just for test.c.

Answer (score 6):

`-O2` is a **compilation** flag. The only input you're compiling in this example is `test.c`. `mystaticlib.a` is not compiled, but rather **linked** with the compilation output of `test.c` to create the executable `test`. Since `mystaticlib.a` isn't compiled here, the `-O2` flag does not affect it.